# add one column to dataframe based on the change in the other column in R

Tags: r

I am having a dataframe as like below. Build used to change weekly twise or
once. Whenever it get changed, It needs to be get identified in the ggplot
graph by adding one more scatter plot(let me know if there is better idea)
using the same x axis(date).

For that I thought to add one more column to this dataframe.

```
              date                                  build Runtime
    2   2013-07-16                  build-2013-07-09-1332 672.918
    4   2013-07-17                  build-2013-07-15-0510 696.924
    6   2013-07-18                  build-2013-07-15-0510 736.720
    8   2013-07-19                  build-2013-07-18-1644 693.206
    10  2013-07-20                  build-2013-07-18-1644 699.332
    12  2013-07-24                  build-2013-07-22-0510 712.388
    14  2013-07-25                  build-2013-07-22-0510 711.573
    16  2013-07-26                  build-2013-07-22-0510 715.223
    18  2013-07-27                  build-2013-07-22-0510 715.180
    20  2013-07-31                  build-2013-07-29-0510 717.888
    22  2013-08-01                  build-2013-07-29-0510 716.315
    24  2013-08-02                  build-2013-07-29-0510 719.216
    26  2013-08-03                  build-2013-07-29-0510 716.073
    28  2013-08-07                  build-2013-08-05-0510 717.566
```

Added one more column called BuildChange as like below. Used awk command to do
the same.

```
    cat q.txt | awk 'BEGIN{CBD=""}{if($3 != CDB){print $2","$3","$4","1}else{print $2","$3","$4","0}CDB=$3;}'


              date                                  build Runtime BuildChange
    2   2013-07-16                  build-2013-07-09-1332 672.918 5
    4   2013-07-17                  build-2013-07-15-0510 696.924 5
    6   2013-07-18                  build-2013-07-15-0510 736.720
    8   2013-07-19                  build-2013-07-18-1644 693.206 5
    10  2013-07-20                  build-2013-07-18-1644 699.332
    12  2013-07-24                  build-2013-07-22-0510 712.388 5
    14  2013-07-25                  build-2013-07-22-0510 711.573
    16  2013-07-26                  build-2013-07-22-0510 715.223
    18  2013-07-27                  build-2013-07-22-0510 715.180
    20  2013-07-31                  build-2013-07-29-0510 717.888 5
    22  2013-08-01                  build-2013-07-29-0510 716.315
    24  2013-08-02                  build-2013-07-29-0510 719.216
    26  2013-08-03                  build-2013-07-29-0510 716.073
    28  2013-08-07                  build-2013-08-05-0510 717.566 5
```

I'm thinking to do the same in for loop. Is there a better idea to add one
more column and display the change of build in the graph.

Result graph but I want without above and right axis

[image: Result graph but I want without above and right axis]

dput() for my dataframe

```
    structure(list(date = structure(1:28, .Label = c("2013-07-16",
    "2013-07-17", "2013-07-18", "2013-07-19", "2013-07-20", "2013-07-24",
    "2013-07-25", "2013-07-26", "2013-07-27", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-01",
    "2013-08-02", "2013-08-03", "2013-08-07", "2013-08-08", "2013-08-09",
    "2013-08-10", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-15", "2013-08-16", "2013-08-17",
    "2013-08-21", "2013-08-22", "2013-08-23", "2013-08-24", "2013-08-28",
    "2013-08-29", "2013-08-30", "2013-08-31", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-05",
    "2013-09-06", "2013-09-07", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-12", "2013-09-13",
    "2013-09-18", "2013-09-19", "2013-09-20", "2013-09-21", "2013-09-25",
    "2013-09-26", "2013-09-27", "2013-09-28", "2013-10-02", "2013-10-03",
    "2013-10-04", "2013-10-05", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-10", "2013-10-11",
    "2013-10-12", "2013-10-16", "2013-10-17", "2013-10-18", "2013-10-19",
    "2013-10-23", "2013-10-24", "2013-10-25", "2013-10-26", "2013-10-30",
    "2013-10-31", "2013-11-01", "2013-11-02", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-07",
    "2013-11-08", "2013-11-09"), class = "factor"), build = structure(c(1L,
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("build-2013-07-09-1332",
    "build-2013-07-15-0510", "build-2013-07-18-1644",
    "build-2013-07-22-0510", "build-2013-07-29-0510",
    "build-2013-08-05-0510", "build-2013-08-13-1329",
    "build-2013-08-20-0510", "build-2013-08-27-0510",
    "build-2013-09-03-1340", "build-2013-09-10-1326",
    "build-2013-09-17-0510", "build-2013-09-26-0510",
    "build-2013-10-08-1359", "build-2013-10-14-0510",
    "build-2013-10-18-1437", "build-2013-10-18-1437-PLUS-11259-11737",
    "build-2013-10-28-0510", "build-2013-11-04-0510"
    ), class = "factor"), Runtime = c(672.918, 696.924, 736.72, 693.206,
    699.332, 712.388, 711.573, 715.223, 715.18, 717.888, 716.315,
    719.216, 716.073, 717.566, 723.644, 720.374, 726.145, 710.658,
    715.002, 718.742, 727.297, 711.684, 714.743, 715.815, 726.467,
    742.33, 746.352, 749.55)), .Names = c("date", "build", "Runtime"
    ), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L,
    22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 46L,
    48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You may get more help if you `dput()` your data.frame above. Then people can copy/paste it and make an example for you.

Comment: Can you please [show us the R code you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is your dataframe, then something along these lines should get you started.

```
library(ggplot2)

# identify change in build
df$buildchange <- c(1,as.integer(diff(df$build))
df[df$buildchange==0,"buildchange"]=NA

#plot
p1 <- ggplot(
  data = df,
  aes(
    x = date)) + 
  geom_line(
    aes(
      y = Runtime,
      group = 1,
      colour = "Runtime")
    ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      y = Runtime*buildchange,
      size = 5,
      colour = "Build Change")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this - square shows average runtime for that build. Note the new column not required.

```
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)

df1$date<-(as.Date(df1$date))

ggplot(data=df1)+
  geom_line(aes(date,Runtime))+
  geom_point(data=ddply(df1,.(build),summarize,firstdate=min(date),avruntime=mean(Runtime)),
         aes(firstdate,avruntime),
         shape=22,
         size=5,
         fill="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would tick the X-axis each time a new build was released. From the original plot you can extract the minimum values of y and set the y-axis for all the ticks to this minimum, thus this code is generic and keeps working when the runtime drops below the current lowpoint. Putting the original data in `Dat` this is the code[image]

```
p <-  ggplot(Dat, aes(date, Runtime)) + geom_line()
buildElements <- strsplit(as.character(Dat$build), split = "-")
pasteBE <- function(x)  paste(x[2],x[3],x[4], sep = "-")
Dat2 <- data.frame(
  newBuild = as.Date(unique(sapply(buildElements, pasteBE))),
  yMin = ggplot_build(p)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range[1])
p + geom_point(data = Dat2, aes(newBuild, yMin), col = "red", size = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the `dput()` it has no build change column.

I think you want something like this? The buildChange data is imported as NA so doesn't show as points. Then I just calculate the max runtime and nudge the points above the graph so the y axes scale nice. Hacky but well... it's lunchtime.

```
# I added an id identifier to the first column of q.txt
DF= read.table('q.txt', header=T, fill=T, colClasses=c('numeric', 'Date', 'factor', 'numeric', 'numeric'))
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
m=max(DF$Runtime)
qplot(date,Runtime, geom='line',data=DF)+geom_point(aes(x=date, y=BuildChange+m+5))
```

which gives me:

[image]